# How to convert an array to a matrix and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I was trying to solve a 2D matrix problem, and stumble upon the matrix-array convert formula:

```
r * c matrix convert to an array => matrix[x][y] => arr[x * c + y]
an array convert to r * c matrix => arr[x] =>matrix[x / c][x % c]
```

But I can't seem to understand why it works like this. Can someone explain how the conversion works? I mean why the conversions manipulate the columns(c)? And why using subtraction and remainder([x / c][x % c])? And why x * c + y?

I was solving the problem in JavaScript.

Comment: Bring out some pen and paper. Draw a grid to represent a matrix, and write the indices of each cell in. Then try some random examples and see why it the math works.

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at ["Row Major Vs Column Major Order: 2D arrays access in programming languages"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71985/row-major-vs-column-major-order-2d-arrays-access-in-programming-languages) on Computing Science Stack Overflow as an insight to the main ways an array can be serialized:

1. Row order stores all the values for a row contiguously in serialized output, starting with first row, before proceeding to the next row.
2. Column order stores all the values for a column in serialized output, starting with the first column before proceeding to the next.

**Formula Confusion**

The quoted formula creates output in row order because it multiplies one of the indexes by the number of columns, not the number of rows, which means index `x` is being used as the row index. This is nonsensical in a spread sheet context where "x" means column and "y" means row.

**JavaScript Formula for row order storage of a row/column matrix**

```
 matrix[row][column]   is serialized to  arr[row * c + col]
 arr[index]   is restored to   matrix[ Math.floor(index/c), index % c]
```

where calculating the row in de-serialization requires truncation of the division result since there is no integral division operator in JavaScript to match that used in the quoted formula.

**Typical JavaScript Application**

[`imageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) store canvas pixel data in row order:

> Pixels then proceed from left to right, then downward, throughout the [serialized] array.

It's not that you can't use `x` and `y` variable names to access image pixel data, but bear in mind `x` is a column index, and `y` is the row number from the top.